# bootstrap error ios simulator

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator, ipad

I tried to launch my project, but i got this error while compiling it on the simulator.WorkOut is the name of my project.

Couldn't register com.AE557593PG.WorkOut with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making sure the app isn't running on the simulator already. Worst case scenario, quit and restart both Simulator and Xcode. That's always fixed this for me.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run the project again and it did work. I think it was coz same other thread was accessing it.